# Babel 'decorators' plugin error compiling with webpack

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm getting a webpack compilation error

```
Module build failed: Error: The 'decorators' plugin requires a 'decoratorsBeforeExport' option, whose value must be a boolean. If you are migrating from Babylon/Babel 6 or want to use the old decorators proposal, you should use the 'decorators-legacy' plugin instead of 'decorators'.
```

I tried adding `['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', { decoratorsBeforeExport: true }]` as the error message's instruction, but I'm still getting the same error. Here's the babel part of my webpack config

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                    '@babel/preset-env',
                    '@babel/preset-stage-0', 
                ],
                plugins: [
                    'transform-class-properties',
                    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'
                ]
            }
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: true
    })
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the culprit was `@babel/preset-stage-0` by trying the options/plugins one by one while all the others commented out. I also found out that with babel 7+ you don't need `preset-stage-x`, so I just deleted it, and now it works. The working setting is:

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
        presets: [
            '@babel/preset-env',
        ],
        plugins: [
            'transform-class-properties',
            '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'
        ]
    }
}
```